# Are there animals / mammals which only have one eye?

Tags: zoology, vision, eyes, sensory-systems

Do all animals (of a certain size and not thinking about worms) have the possibility to perceive depth?

Do all mammals have at least two eyes? Are there mammals with more than two eyes?

Comment: Not all two-eyed mammals have depth perception. Many herbivores have eyes on the opposite sides of their head to increase their range of vision for predators, and are so widely separated that they barely overlap at the front, if at all.

Comment: Also, please clarify "*all animals (of a certain size and not thinking about worms)*".

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you for your first comment; I didn't think of that. For the second: I am aware of the fact that some worms (all?) don't have eyes. Also, I'm not interested of animals which consist of a very small number of cells (by a quick search I found Myxozoa as an example). So for the sake of clarity, lets say the animal has to have at least 5cm of height when standing on the ground.